# Creating a Bookmarklet Dependent on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I'm using Mr Coles' Bookmarklet creator( http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/ ), but I just can't seem to get this javascript to run properly.  This is the javascript I want to run after the page loads.  It should popup the email and phone number it found on the page.  If jQuery is included on the page, and i paste this into console, then it runs fine, but from the bookmarklet it errors differently based on which generator used.

```
helper = {};
helper.extractEmails = function (text) {
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}
email = "", phone = "";
if ($('a[href^="mailto"]').length > 0) {
    email = $('a[href^="mailto"]').attr("href").replace("mailto:", "").trim();
} else {
    email = helper.extractEmails($("body").html());
    if (email != null && email.length > 0) {
        email = email[0];
    }
}
if (email == null) {
    email = "";
}
phones = [];
str = $("body").text();
reg = /[0-9-()+]{10,20}/ig;
phoneNumber = /[0-9-()+]{10,20}/ig;
phones.push(str.match(phoneNumber)[0]);
if (phones.length > 0) {
    phone = phones[0];
}
alert("Email: " + email + "\r\nPhone: " + phone);
```

Here is the exact bookmartlet code:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bfunction%20callback()%7B(function(%24)%7Bvar%20jQuery%3D%24%3Bhelper%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3Bhelper.extractEmails%20%3D%20function(%20text%20)%20%7Breturn%20text.match(%2F(%5Ba-zA-Z0-9._-%5D%2B%40%5Ba-zA-Z0-9._-%5D%2B%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z0-9._-%5D%2B)%2Fgi)%3B%7Demail%20%3D%20%22%22%2Cphone%20%3D%20%22%22%3Bif(%24('a%5Bhref%5E%3D%22mailto%22%5D').length%20%3E%200)%20%7Bemail%20%3D%20%24('a%5Bhref%5E%3D%22mailto%22%5D').attr(%22href%22).replace(%22mailto%3A%22%2C%20%22%22).trim()%3B%7D%20else%20%7Bemail%20%3D%20helper.extractEmails(%24(%22body%22).html())%3Bif(email%20!%3D%20null%20%26%26%20email.length%3E0)%20%7Bemail%20%3D%20email%5B0%5D%3B%7D%7Dif(email%20%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%20email%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%7Dphones%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3Bstr%20%3D%20%24(%22body%22).text()%3Breg%20%3D%20%2F%5B0-9-()%2B%5D%7B10%2C20%7D%2Fig%3BphoneNumber%20%3D%20%2F%5B0-9-()%2B%5D%7B10%2C20%7D%2Fig%3Bphones.push(str.match(phoneNumber)%5B0%5D)%3Bif(phones.length%20%3E%200)%20%7Bphone%20%3D%20phones%5B0%5D%3B%7Dalert(%22Email%3A%20%22%2Bemail%2B%22%5Cr%5CnPhone%3A%20%22%2Bphone)%7D)(jQuery.noConflict(true))%7Dvar%20s%3Ddocument.createElement(%22script%22)%3Bs.src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.7.1%2Fjquery.min.js%22%3Bif(s.addEventListener)%7Bs.addEventListener(%22load%22%2Ccallback%2Cfalse)%7Delse%20if(s.readyState)%7Bs.onreadystatechange%3Dcallback%7Ddocument.body.appendChild(s)%3B%7D)()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... A-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);}email = "",pho ...
                                       └─ You are missing a ";" at column 187.
```

It is actually not the generator's fault because you are missing the semicolon in your code:

```
helper.extractEmails = function (text) {
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}
```

Now if you add it back, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/3HrMB/2/

---

Next time you can use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to see where the problem is:

[image]